# convert a php string array into a js array in js

Tags: php, javascript

I have an array from data that's retrieved from AJAX (which it comes from MVC-view-cakephp). I want to refill the array into combobox. Array looks like this:

```
Array (
    [266] => Andy Employee II
    [26] => Annette Oliveira
    [214] => Edwina Umeyor
    [39] => Eva Britton
    [193] => Leigh Otterson
    [68] => Louise Edelston
    [71] => Margaret Williams
    [97] => Simon Harris
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would use the php [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = <?php echo json_encode($myarray);?>;
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need to use any tag. like<script></script>... otherwise You wont have any thing in your array

Answer (score 2):

You will use the `json_encode` function to turn a PHP array into a JavaScript object. More information on `json_encode` can be found in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you'd have to write a custom parser to do this. You're unlikely to find one on the internet.

The preferable solution here is to have the cakephp script output this array as JSON. JSON can be easily produced by php using `json_encode` and of course javascript is very good at reading a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't have associative arrays.  Instead, they use objects.  In your PHP echo json_encode( $yourArray ); instead of whatever you are returning now (looks like a vardump?).

In your AJAX call set up JSON to be the expected content return type.